# How to fix iframe scrolling issue for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am getting content from word press via java script function into an i frame, you can see the code below..I am getting an additional scroll bar for IE  I want remove that scroll.![enter image description here][1]

```
<iframe id="content Frame" name="content Frame" 
        onload="apply Style Sheet(this); scroll Page();" 
        src="home.html" frame border="0" seamless="" 
        style="overflow: hidden; height: 729px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding scrolling="no" to the iframe.

iFrame tag on page:

```
<iframe id="contentFrame" 
        name="contentFrame" 
        onload="applyStyleSheet(this); scrollPage();" 
        src="home.html" frameborder="0" 
        seamless="" 
        style="overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Hi Wittakarn, There is a small issue using scroll no, since there is a payment gateway related to the website, I am unable to use scroll no, is there any other way to fix it ?